# windows 10 unable to create a file having path more than 247 characters

Tags: windows-10

i am using **Microsoft Windows Version 2004 (OS Build 19041.329)**
unable to create a file at a path more then 247 characters as following

```
C:\Users\NavpreetDevpuri\Downloads\LyndaDownloader-master\LyndaDownloader-master\Lynda\Become a Full-Stack Web Developer\2. PHP with MySQL Essential Training 1 The Basics (5h 51m) 720p\1. Start a Database-Driven Project\00000000000000000000000.txt
```

on emore example a file on desktop as follow having 247 characters at maximum.

```
C:\Users\NavpreetDevpuri\Desktop\gasdfgasdrgvsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfsdsdsdfgsdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd.txt
```

I tried to restart and shotdown after changing following settngs

### I tried to change following but it did not work.

1. **Group Policy** to `1`

```
Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Filesystem -> Enable Win32 long paths
```

2. **Filesystem Registry entry** to `1`

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled
```

3. **Group Policy Registry entry** to `1`

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Policies\LongPathsEnabled
```

But following **Group Policy** is missing as mentioned at many online resources. may be this is the problem.

```
Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Filesystem -> NTFS -> Enable NTFS long paths
```

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Windows Version 2004 (OS Build 19041.329)

Comment: If you are trying to navigate to that path with File Explorer that isn't going to work on any version of Windows 10.  File Explorer has not been updated to support it.  [This is well documented by the way.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).  I fully understand the duplicate was asked about 1607 but the answer has not actually changed

Comment: understood
i was unable to create a file by using a python scrpt then i just tried to create a file using file explorer and it did not work. after changing those mentioned settings now my python script is able to create files and i can navigate to those paths inside file explorer. But i can't able to create files using file explorer.